# Multiple Web Service Data in a gridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm connecting two different web services that produce the same structure of data.  The example code below will give me grand total results.

Example:

```
ItemSKU1  ItemName1  TotalQuantity1
ItemSKU2  ItemName2  TotalQuantity2
...
```

I want to be able to seperate the results of the web service to something like this:

```
ItemSKU1  ItemName1  QuantityIP1  QuantityIP2
...
```

Example code:

```
Dim returnds As New DataSet
Dim myreport As New RE.RE
Dim tmpURL = {"IP1", "IP2"}
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 1


        Try

            myreport.Url = "http://" & tmpURL(i) & "/RE.asmx"
            returnds = myreport.GetDeptDetails(date1, date2, dept)
            Me.gvReorder.DataSource = returnds
            Me.gvReorder.DataBind()
            returnds.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            label.visible = true
            label.text = "Error: " & ex.Message
        End Try

    Next
```

How can I do this when IP1 results are SKU and IP2 results SKU with out try to merge multiple datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by editing the datatable:

```
Dim tmpEditRow As DataRow = tmpReturnRows(0)

                    tmpEditRow.BeginEdit()

                    Select Case a

                        Case 0

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH1") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 1

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH3") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 2

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH4") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 3

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH7") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 4

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH8") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 5

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH10") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 6

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH12") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                        Case 7

                            tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH14") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH

                    End Select

                    tmpEditRow.EndEdit()
```